# decrypting an encrypted message (that I encrypted)

Tags: javascript, arrays, encryption

I'm working on a very simple encryption program. I start with an input message, password, output and 2 buttons.

```
<input type="text" id="message"></input><br>
<input type="text" id="password"></input>
<p id="encrypted"></p>

<button class="trans" id="button-encrypt">encrypt!</button>
<button class="trans" id="button-decrypt">decrypt!</button>
```

When I press button-encrypt, this happens:

1. capture the password string and turn it into a number
2. the number is used to generate an array of 26 letters
3. map letters in the message to the array (called mapArray)

Step 3 looks something like this:

```
    var mapToMapArray = {
      a: mapArray[0], b: mapArray[1], c: mapArray[2]...
    };

    //this code courtesy of another user from here on stackoverflow
    encryptedEl.innerHTML = messageEl.split("").map((letter) => mapToMapArray[letter] || letter).join("");
```

Basically, when I hit the encrypt button, the output is gibberish. That gibberish is different depending on the password I enter. For example, if I enter 'hank' as the message and 'abcde' as the password, the output is 'afbz'. If I enter 'hank' as the message and 'pine' as the password, 'yvza' is the output.

Question:

Now what I want is to reverse the process when I hit the decrypt button. If I enter 'yvza' with password 'pine', I want 'hank' to be the output. I don't know how to do that. Anyhow, I regard myself as a beginner so I apologize if the solution is obvious.

Comment: Find the position of the encrypted letter in your password array (array.indexOf).  If the position is 0, the unencrypted letter is a, 1=b, and so on.

Comment: Something like `unencryptedEl.innerHTML = encryptedEl.split("").map(letter => String.fromCharCode(mapArray.indexOf(letter) + 65)).join("");` (untested)

Comment: i just tried a: String.fromCharCode(97+mapArray.indexOf("a")) inside  mapToMapArray and it worked (for the letter 'a'). I'll try it inside the map() method but I think this is exactly the solution I've been looking for

Answer (score -1):

```js
var message = document.getElementById("message"),
    password = document.getElementById("password"),
    encrypted = document.getElementById("encrypted"),
    decrypted = document.getElementById("decrypted"),
    output = document.getElementById("output");
function loop(array, callback) {
    var len = array.length,
      index;
    for (index = len - 1; index >= 0; index -= 1) {
      callback.call(index, array[index], index);
    }
 }
encrypted.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(message.value!="" && password.value!=""){
    var passi = 0;
    var ec = message.value.replace(/[\w|\W]/g, function(a){
      var pv = password.value[passi].charCodeAt(0);
      passi+=1;
      if(passi>=password.value.length){
        passi=0;
      }
      var av = a.charCodeAt(0);
      return String.fromCharCode(pv+av);
    });
    output.value = btoa(ec);
  }
});
decrypted.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(output.value!="" && password.value!=""){
    var passi = 0;
    var dc = atob(output.value).replace(/[\w|\W]/g, function(a){
      var pv = password.value[passi].charCodeAt(0);
      passi+=1;
      if(passi>=password.value.length){
        passi=0;
      }
      var av = a.charCodeAt(0);
      return String.fromCharCode(av-pv);
    });
    output.value = dc;
  }
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="message" id="message" value="abcdefg">
<input placeholder="password" id="password" value="123">
<br>
<button id="encrypted">encrypted</button>
<button id="decrypted">decrypted</button>
<br>
<input placeholder="output" id="output">
```